# Vaadin Addon doesnt work, not showing component

Tags: java, vaadin, add-on

I want to use the zXingVaadin Addon, in case to provide the function to scan QR Codes.
Using the following code:

```
public ZXingVaadinReader zXingVaadin;
FlexLayout flexLayout;

public FlexLayout getQRScanButton() {
    flexLayout = new FlexLayout();
    Div div = new Div();
    div.getStyle().set("height", "100px").set("width", "100px").set("background-color", "grey");
    div.add(getzXingVaadinReader());
    flexLayout.add(div);
    flexLayout.setId("outerQRDiv");

    return flexLayout;
}

private ZXingVaadinReader getzXingVaadinReader() {
    zXingVaadin = new ZXingVaadinReader();
    zXingVaadin.setFrom(Constants.From.camera);
    zXingVaadin.setId("video");
    return zXingVaadin;
}
```

and this in the MainView:

```
QrScanButton qrScanButton = new QrScanButton();
    add(qrScanButton.getQRScanButton());
```

i only get an empty zXingVaadinReader Component with the size 0x0. I dont understand what the problem is.

Link to the Vaadin Addon:
https://vaadin.com/directory/component/zxingvaadin

I also imported the dependency as shown on the website in the pom.xml file

Comment: If you inspect the element, is the shadow DOM rendered? Try `zXingVaadin.setSizeFull()`.